# React Changing CSS background on update

Tags: css, reactjs

Trying to toggle the CSS background image in this React app. I've imported the images. And then I set a variable "image" to the imported image as the iteration increases/decreases on click.

Problem is the body background image doesn't seem to update. I thought that a background image would refresh in componentDidUpdate because the iterative buttons toggle setState which should force a render.

```
import Background1 from "../images/bg/1.png";
import Background2 from "../images/bg/3.png";
import Background3 from "../images/bg/4.png";


class UserPreferences extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      backgroundNumber: 1
    };
  }

  buttonNumberCalcPlus = () => {
    this.setState({ backgroundNumber: ++this.state.backgroundNumber });
  };

  buttonNumberCalcMinus = () => {
    this.setState({ backgroundNumber: --this.state.backgroundNumber });
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    var currentBackground = "Background" + this.state.backgroundNumber;
    console.log(currentBackground);

    var image;

    if (this.state.backgroundNumber == 1) {
      image = Background1;
    } else if (this.state.backgroundNumber == 2) {
      image = Background2;
    } else {
      image = Background3;
    }

    var mainBg = {
      backgroundImage: "url( " + { image } + ")"
    };
    console.log(mainBg);
    document.body.style = { mainBg };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MainMenuToolbar />
        <h2 className="texttimezonepref">Change background image.</h2>
        <button
          id="next"
          onClick={this.buttonNumberCalcPlus}
          className="addbutton"
        >
          NEXT
        </button>
        <button
          id="prev"
          onClick={this.buttonNumberCalcMinus}
          className="subtractbutton"
        >
          PREV
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is this the correct way to change the background in componentDidUpdate:

```
var mainBg = {
  backgroundImage: "url( " + { image } + ")"
};


document.body.style = { mainBg };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document.body.style is not JSX, and does not accept the `document.body.style = {{ backgroundImage: "url( " + { image } + ")"}}` as you're expecting.

Instead, you want to just apply your style change to the target directly, such as:

`document.body.style.backgroundImage = url(image)`

Comment: Failed to compile.'url' is not defined

Comment: Thanks. This worked: document.body.style.backgroundImage =  "url(${image})"

Comment: Ahh yeah - I see I missed the double quotes, sorry about that just wrote it out quick :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning an object to the `style` property use `style.background`. This is required because `style` isn't a plain object but a `CSSStyleDeclaration`. You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

Regarding the document access: You can do it this way but I recommend to use [`react-helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) which provides a nice way to update the document.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct way to change the background in componentDidUpdate?

No, it isn't.

The body of the document is not the only element that can use the full viewport and it's not recommended to have your app fiddle with the body of the document too much. Your app is inside a `<div id="#root">` most of the time, so you should change the style prop of your root div instead of that of the body.

By using document.body you're skipping React entirely by directly trying to apply changes to the DOM node. That should only be done using [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).